# Need an API design pattern where I can expose the same api to background process and end clients

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-ad-b2c

Our apis are being consumed by 3rd party deamon applications as well as client applications. For third party deamon application we can expose the api via the client credential oauth flow and for the client application(S) we use the implicit grant outh flow.

The challenge we are facing is that in case of the implicit grant flow the user details are fetched from the ACCESS TOKEN.  But when the same api is used for the client credential flow the user details can not be fetched from the ACCESS token as it has only application specific details.

What is the the best api design approach to handle the above challenge ?
Do I need two set of api(s) one for integrating with client application and one for integrating with server application ?
Will the usage of any alternative oauth flow help ?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to Authentication scenarios for Azure AD documentation, as you stated correctly user interaction is not possible with a daemon application, which requires the application to have its own identity. This type of application requests an access token by using its application identity and presenting its Application ID, credential (password or certificate), and application ID URI to Azure AD. After successful authentication, the daemon receives an access token from Azure AD, which is then used to call the web API.

The quintessential OAuth2 authorization code grant is the authorization grant that uses two separate endpoints. The authorization endpoint is used for the user interaction phase, which results in an authorization code. The token endpoint is then used by the client for exchanging the code for an access token, and often a refresh token as well. Web applications are required to present their own application credentials to the token endpoint, so that the authorization server can authenticate the client.

Hence, the recommended way is two have two version of api implemented with two different type of authentication based on your scenario.

Reference -

[Daemon or server application to web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#daemon-or-server-application-to-web-api)
[Understanding the OAuth2 implicit grant flow in Azure Active Directory (AD)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-dev-understanding-oauth2-implicit-grant)